# Google places autocomplete library

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am wanting to restrict the search results of a google places search to just locations in the UK on reading the documentation I have add an attribute the libraries URL,

`components=country:gb`

I have added this so my script src now looks like,

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_API_KEY}&libraries=places&components=country:gb&callback=initMap`

But i can still return results from outside of the UK, I assume I am doing some wrong with my script src?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a param of the service not the request URL, so I had to do,

```
return this.service.getPlacePredictions({
    input: searchValue,
    componentRestrictions: { country: 'gb'}
}, this.displayResults.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Kindly replace gb with uk

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_API_KEY}&libraries=places&components=country:gb&callback=initMap](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%7BMY_API_KEY%7D&libraries=places&components=country:gb&callback=initMap)